# Iterating over groups of rows in separate data frames R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, nested-loops

I have two different data frames of different lengths looking something like this (not all rows shown here):

```
all_eeg

       EEG    Recording
88     55.746      AA00
89     56.277      AA00
90     56.738      AA00
91     57.159      AA00
92     57.550      AA00
93     57.817      AA00

1549   51.001      AB00
1550   51.504      AB00
1551   51.609      AB00
1552   52.080      AB00
1553   52.461      AB00
1554   52.977      AB00
1555   53.366      AB00

6260 1000.644      AF01
6261 1000.745      AF01
6262 1001.800      AF01
6263 1002.180      AF01
6264 1003.333      AF01
6265 1004.230      AF01


all_1p

         Time LFP_Latency LFP_Amplitude Peak_LFP_Length Recording Electrode
1     57.1184     7.11995        -0.414         8.46697      AA00         1
2    123.3470     5.32393        -0.018         5.00321      AA00         1
3    191.0920    10.58370        -0.426         5.38807      AA00         1
4    249.1710     4.49006        -0.042         5.25978      AA00         1
5    325.5090     7.11995        -0.486         7.69724      AA00         1
6    385.6040     5.77293        -0.012         4.04105      AA00         1

131    51.730     8.86496      -1.22667         5.71567      AB00         1
132   117.684     8.62209      -2.56667         3.93459      AB00         1
133   184.974     8.20110      -3.51333         3.62694      AB00         1
134   242.875     7.39152      -3.50667         4.77655      AB00         1
135   319.604     7.42390      -2.74667         4.30699      AB00         1
136   379.350     8.81639      -1.06000         5.97474      AB00         1
137   430.632    10.74320      -1.81333         4.19365      AB00         1

296 1003.4300     4.09302      -1.90800         7.93798      AF01         2
297 1072.0500    11.16280      -2.48400         5.76744      AF01         2
298 1132.8900     8.93023      -1.39200         7.19380      AF01         2
299 1197.8800     6.63566      -1.03200        10.35660      AF01         2
300 1259.2800    10.23260      -2.98800         8.18605      AF01         2
301   61.8331    10.03750      -2.08600         5.25328      AF02         2
```

I want to create a new data frame (or remove rows from all_eeg). The rows I want to "keep" should be based on the number from all_eeg$EEG that is the closest smaller number to each of the numbers in all_1p$Time **if and only if** they belong to the same Recording. So I am thinking that the code first should iterate over rows in all_1p$Recording and search for the rows in all_eeg$Recording that has the same values, then iterate over the indexes in all_1p$Time and then identify the closest smaller number in all_eeg$EEG. So the first row in the new data frame will be row 90 from all_eeg because it contains the closest smaller number to the first index in all_1p$Time belonging to the same recording.

I tried writing a loop, but something is off.

```
pre_eeg_list <- c()

for(i in 1:nrow(all_1p)){
   if(all_1p$Recording[i] == all_eeg$Recording){
    pre_eeg_list[i] <- max(all_eeg$EEG[all_1p$Time[i] >= all_eeg$EEG]) 
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I could be done easily with dplyr package.

```
> Library(dplyr) 
> all_eeg %>%  left_join(all_1p %>% group_by(Recording) 
> %>% summarize(min_time = min(Time)) ) %>% mutate(time_delta = Time -
> min_time) %>% group_by(Recording) %>% filter(time_delta =
> min(time_delta))
```

- Step 1: Find the minimum time by each recording
- Step 2: Left join the
  minimum time with all_eeg and find the time delta between time and minimum time
- Step 3:Filter lowest time delta by each recording

Comment: Thank you! I see what you´re doing. I do, however, get an error:

````
Error in eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'Time' not found
```
I tried with dplyr::summarize, but that doesn't seem to help. I shouldn´t specify which data frame Time belongs to in tidyverse, right? Like all_1p$Time

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `dplyr` from the `tidyverse` collection of packages for this kind of problem. Also, in the future, you might want to provide the example data in a format that's directly copy-paste'able into R. I haven't tested it, but something like this should answer your problem.

```
library(tidyverse)

all_eeg %>%
    inner_join(all_1p, by = "Recording") %>%
    mutate(t_diff = Time - EEG) %>%
    group_by("Recording", "Time") %>%
    filter(t_diff == min(t_diff))
```